# Laravel set state column

Tags: laravel, migration, constants

I am wanting to add a new column to my film table called `status` which has two options `active` or `inactive` i am wanting to set all the current films in the DB to be active by default.

My first thought is to create a library file with the states set as constants incase i ever decide to add more down the line. e.g

```
const active = 1;
const inactive = 2;
```

can i then just pass the constant in as a default in the new column?

**migration file**

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('films', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('status')->default(\App\Library\Status::active);
    });
}
```

some help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set datatype as an `enum` and set a value as `active` and `deactive` with default value `active` it'll automatically set `active` you don't need to pass it by const.

```
$table->enum('status',['active','deactive'])->default('active');
```

Comment: ahh interesting! what if you want to add more to the status list do you just add them into the array brackets? when i come to adding logic down the line where it changes the status depending on if a admin suspends someone would using this way still be ideal or would you use const then?

Comment: Yes, If you want to add more status then add it in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice with Comments

```
$table->enum('status',['Active','InActive'])
            ->default('Active')->comment('Active/Deactive');
```